# R unused arguments error on user defined function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to run this function on my data frame to add columns. I keep getting this error. `Error in addTicketColumns(., df = train_data) : unused argument (.)` this is my code:

````
library(tidyverse) 
library(modelr) 
train_data <-as.data.frame(read_csv("titanic/train.csv")) 
test_data <- as.data.frame(read_csv("titanic/test.csv")) 

addTicketColumns <- function(df){ df %>% cbind(df,"Ticket_Letters", "Ticket_Numbers") 
+ df$"Ticket_Letters" == "NA" 
+ df$"Ticket_Numbers" == "NA"} 

ticketSplit <- function(df) { 
+ for (i in seq_along(df$"Ticket")) { + if (grepl(" ",df$"Ticket"[[i]])) { 
+ ticket %>% separate("Ticket", c('Ticket_Letters','Ticket_Numbers')) } else { df$"Ticket_Numbers"[[i]] <- as.double(ticket) df$Ticket_Letters = "NA"}}} ``` 

train_data %\>% addTicketColumns(df = train_data)\` thank you for your time and consideration.
````

Comment: There are many problems in your code, even beyond the fact that you haven't provided reproducible data for us to use as `train_data`  and `test_data`. First, you've copied and pasted in a way that has brought extraneous `+` characters on the left-hand side of your indented lines, which means it won't run as-is. Second, you seem to be using `==` for assignment, instead of `=`. Third, your last line uses `%\>%`, when I think you want `%>%`. Finally, your `ticketSplit` function isn't even called, so it's not clear what it's doing.

Comment: Notwithstanding my above comments, I think the real reason you're getting that error is that you are passing `train_data` directly to `addTicketColumns` via the `%>%` pipe, and then also trying to call your function on `df = train_data`. R interprets this as you trying to pass two arguments to a function that only takes one, so it throws an error indicating that you are passing it an argument that isn't used. Just call `train_data %>% addTicketColumns()` or `addTicketColumns(train_data)`.

Comment: @C.Murtaugh ok sorry about the code, I had to copy and paste on my phone from an email to myself. When I try to do this it gives me an error saying unused argument addTicketColumns(., train_data). I only defined the function to have df as an argument.

Comment: Did you try to simply call `addTicketColumns(train_data)` on its own? That worked for me, with a dummy data frame (and after correcting `==` to `=` in the body of your function). No matter how you define a function, if you pass it too many arguments, you’ll get that error, and in your case you are calling it with 2x `train_data`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this has a wild amount of errors. I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do, but my best guess is that the ticket has some letters followed by a space and then some numbers. You want to separate the letters and numbers, but some of the tickets only have numbers. This would only need a little regex to solve.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_datat <- tibble(Ticket = c("aa 231", "3255", "bb 2200", "cc 124", "3"))
test_datat
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   Ticket 
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 aa 231 
#> 2 3255   
#> 3 bb 2200
#> 4 cc 124 
#> 5 3

ticketSplit <- function(df){
  df %>%
    mutate(Ticket_Letters = str_extract(Ticket, "[a-zA-Z]+"),
           Ticket_Numbers = as.numeric(str_extract(Ticket, "\\d+")))
    
}

ticketSplit(test_datat)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   Ticket  Ticket_Letters Ticket_Numbers
#>   <chr>   <chr>                   <dbl>
#> 1 aa 231  aa                        231
#> 2 3255    <NA>                     3255
#> 3 bb 2200 bb                       2200
#> 4 cc 124  cc                        124
#> 5 3       <NA>                        3
```